# Javascript - expand div to fit contents but not expand outside of container

Tags: html, css, overflow, containers, expand

Is it possible to do this with CSS?  Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="left">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="top">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            dynamic content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want `bottom` to scroll if it overflows the space between top and the bottom of `main-container`.

How can this be done without specifying the height of `bottom`?

I would prefer not to specify height on other elements either if possible.  It doesn't right now, but `top` could have dynamic content as well.

The HTML above can change however necessary; what I require is the end result of a left column, a right column, and the bottom portion of the right column scrolling if its context exceeds the available space in the main container.

Comment: have you tried overflow:scroll on .bottom?

Comment: Setting the overflow property doesn't take effect unless you have also specified the height on the same element.  I am specifically looking for a way to simulate overflow: auto on .bottom without having to specify the height of .bottom.  What I want is a dynamically expanding .bottom, possibly with a dynamically generated .top, that automatically scrolls if it goes beyond the bounds of .main-container.  From what I can tell, there may not be a pure CSS (non-Javascript) solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you'll have to specify some kind of limits (either `height` or `max-height`) to your elements in order to know if the content goes beyond them.

Once you have those dimensions set up, `overflow:auto;` will show you scrollbars when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="left" style="float: left; width:33%">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="float: right; width:66%">
        <div class="top" style="height: auto;">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="bottom" style="max-height: {height of main-cont.}; overflow-y: scroll;">
            dynamic content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not work because I don't want to specify the height of .bottom.  For my purposes specifying max-height creates the same disadvantages that specifying height does, namely that I am looking for a way where .bottom does not have to "know" any specific height measurements.  Also, setting .bottom's max-height to the height of .main-container pushes .bottom out of the bottom of .main-container if height of .top + height of .bottom > height of .main-container.